# Get highest value for each date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a table that logs every time a user completes a survey. It looks a bit like this:

```
    surveyID        author       timestamp
-----------------------------------------------
    1               person1      1461840669000
    2               person2      1461840670000
    3               person1      1461840680000
```

I'm trying to run a query that shows me the top surveyor every day (i.e. the person that does the highest number of surveys per day) since April 1st.

So far I've tried this:

```
SELECT author,
       COUNT (DISTINCT surveyid) AS num_surveys,
       STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(creation_time*1000, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
FROM myTable
WHERE creation_time > 1459468800000 //since April 1st
GROUP BY date, author
ORDER BY 3 DESC,2 DESC;
```

Which gives me this result:

```
author     num_surveys       date
------------------------------------
user1      116            2016-04-27
user2      109            2016-04-27
user3      99             2016-04-27
user3      102            2016-04-28
user1      98             2016-04-28
user2      97             2016-04-28
```

However, I would really just like the top record from each day:

```
author     num_surveys       date
------------------------------------
user1      116            2016-04-27
user3      102            2016-04-28   etc...
```

I've tried `MAX()` and `TOP()` in various places but none of them have worked so far hence the above example of my query that gets me closest to what I want... Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I'm very new to SQL!

### **EDIT**

Thanks for the suggestions to far. Have managed to get it to work with:

```
DEFINE INLINE TABLE A
SELECT author,
COUNT (DISTINCT featureid) AS num_surveys,
STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(creation_time*1000, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
FROM placesense.surveys
WHERE creation_time > 1459468800000
GROUP BY date, author
ORDER BY 3 DESC,2 DESC;

SELECT
MAX(num_surveys),
date
FROM A AS B
WHERE date = B.date
GROUP BY date
```

Any other more efficient suggestions welcome though.

Comment: Perhaps have a play around with 86400 * FLOOR(creation_time/86400000)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.num_surveys = (select max(t2.num_surveys) from t t2 where t2.date = t.date);
```

Note:  this will return duplicates for a date in the case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( surveyid) AS m_surveys,
       STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(creation_time*1000, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
FROM myTable
WHERE creation_time > 1459468800000 //since April 1st
GROUP BY date, author
ORDER BY 3 DESC,2 DESC;
```